# How to output .html to disk using Webpack-dev-server and HTML-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-hot-middleware

I use `webpack` and `html-webpack-plugin` to update my index.html file with the generated script bundle, such as `bundle.[hash].js`.

Then I have to run `webpack-dev-server` so I can load that bundle into memory and take advantage of Hot Module Replacement.

This makes the code compile twice.

However, what I would like is for `webpack-dev-server` to also be able to update the index.html file with the new `bundle.[hash].js`, because now I have to run `webpack` followed by `webpack-dev-sever`. It seems weird to compile twice.

Again, the only reason I run `webpack` is to get my index.html file updated with the new hash of the bundle. If I could get `webpack-dev-server` to output an updated index.html to disk, then I could drop the `webpack` command altogether.

Is this possible? If so, what would the webpack config change be? My webpack config is very long so I didnt think it would help to post it here.

Comment: did you ever find out why it compiles twice. having the same issue...

Comment: Yea, it compiles twice because it is supposed to.`webpack` will compile, and `webpack-dev-server` will compile. I ended up not using `webpack` to update the index.html file and only use `webpack-dev-server` during development, and only `webpack` during production build. You would need to put some excludes in either one to prevent it from compling.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is exactly what you need: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-harddisk-plugin

`webpack-dev-server` saves the updated HTML in memory. With this plugin, it will also write it to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

`webpack-dev-server` would store the compiled bundle in memory, and won't write the bundle to ouput directory, so I think you don't need to add `[hash]` in bundle name when using `webpack-dev-server`,

you could have three webpack config files, say **webpack.common.js**, **webpack.dev.js** and **webpack.prod.js**.

**webpack.common.js** contains common configurations which can be merged with other configurations by using [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge)

**webpack.dev.js** is used for `webpack-dev-server`, and output filename should be `bundle.js`

**webpack.prod.js** is used for production, and the output filename should be `bundle.[hash].js`

then you could simply run `webpack-dev-server webpack.dev.js`

Comment: I am using 3 different configs just like that, from Angular2-webpack-starter. But in order to get my .NET server page `_Layout.cshtml` (which is the main view for the single page app) to load the webpack bundle, `_Layout.cshtml` has to be written to by webpack with the name of the bundle. Therefore, webpack-dev-server cannot update the View with the new bundle hash, and I have to use "webpack" to write the bundle name, and then "webpack-dev-server" to serve the bundle.

Comment: Actually I just realized that it cannot load old hash from webpack-dev-server because there is no cache, it's loaded in memory and cleared any time the dev server stops. So you're correct that I can remove hash from dev bundle.

Comment: New Idea: Is there a way to get `webpack-dev-server` to output assets into wwwroot during build? Or can only `webpack` output assets to disk?